# Execute a Snowflake Stored Procedure from QuickSight Dashboard

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-quicksight

I need to execute a stored procedure in snowflake from a quick sight dashboard.
The parameters for Procedure call statement in QS dashboard is dynamically updated with the values set in the Control Filters. See attached screenshot for more insight.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on QuickSight Community:

> QuickSight supports only select statements currently. Any custom SQL
> that you use to create a data set should also be a select query.

https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/quicksight-query-procedure-in-custom-sql/5782

Answer (score 0):

QuickSight team is currently working on introducing parameters support within QuickSight datasets. When this work is completed, you should be able to build a dashboard where consumers can specify parameters that are passed to Snowflake.
I cannot comment on stored procedures support for Snowflake. I would recommend asking the question at https://community.amazonquicksight.com/ which is a forum provided by Amazon QuickSight team (and that AWS replies to more frequently than stackoverflow)